# Django channels 4.0.0 not working, can't connect to the web socket server

Tags: django, django-channels

Following the official docs, built a small django channel server but when tried to test it using WebSocket King it always throws

> Could not connect to "ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/". You may be able to find more information using Inspector/Dev Tools on this page.

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',

    #Custom apps
    'user_auth',
    'core',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'buddies.asgi.application'
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path

from core.consumers import EchoConsumer

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'buddies.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                # path("chat/admin/", AdminChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                path("chat/", EchoConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})
```

**consumers.py**

```
# it is inside the core app

from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer

class EchoConsumer(SyncConsumer):

    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
        })

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event["text"],
        })
```

When I run the django server it gives no errors (even when I try to ping the server)

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
> January 07, 2024 - 20:58:04
> Django version 5.0.1, using settings 'buddies.settings'
> Starting ASGI/Daphne version 4.0.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tried lowering down the channels version to 3.0.5 and using "channels" in the INSTALLED_APPS, still the issue remained the same.

Comment: Add your JavaScript where you make the connection to the websocket.

Comment: Right now, I am not connecting it to the front end, just want to check that the WebSocket is working.  Hence checking via Websocket King